# JQuery UI Sortable Other Rows Shrink while dragging

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI Sortable for reordering the rows. I have 10 (td) columns out of which I show only 6 and remaining 4 are not shown using display:none.

The issues I am facing are

1. In Chrome while dragging all other rows (not the dragged one) columns shrink and then after dropping the row they get expanded to normal size. Why are the rows columns getting shrink while dragging?
2. In IE8 same as above but after dropping the row they are still in the shrink mode and not expanded to normal size.

Please find the code below. My issue is the other rows width is getting shrink and not the draggable row.

```
            this.$('.reportTableBody').sortable({               
            tolerance:"pointer",
            //TODO need to fix
            cursor: 'move',
            revert: 'true',
            helper: function(e, tr)
            {
                var myHelper = [];
                myHelper.push('<table style="width: 100%">');
                myHelper.push($(tr).html());
                myHelper.push('</table>');
                return myHelper.join('');                   
            },              
            create: function (event, ui) {                  
                 $("td").each(function () {
                        $(this).css("width", $(this).width());
                 });                                         
                if (jQuery.browser.msie && Number(jQuery.browser.version) == 8) {
                    this.$('.reportTableBody').sortable("option", "cursorAt", { top: 100 });
                }
            },
            stop : function(event, ui){                 
                $(ui.item.parent()).find('tr').each(function(index){
                    $(this).find('.yearSelectCell:first').html(index + 1);

                });                 
                ui.item.trigger('drop', ui.item.index());                   
            }});
```

FYI - some of the columns have display:none which would hide the columns. Do you think because of this the column widths are shrinking ?

Comment: show ur code. we cannot guess whats wrong based on ur theory

Answer (score 1):

You can write a **helper** function to specifically set the widths as shown here: http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/, or if your page currently controls the column widths of the table, you can specify **"clone"** for the **helper** option and choose an **appendTo** option that will inherit the styling of the specified selector.

The simplest option for **appendTo** which may work in your case is to set it to the string **"parent"**.  This will cause the dragged helper to be a sibling of the sortable item and thus inherit its styling.

If these options do not suit your need then please post some code or link to a JSFiddle.

Comment: i found where the issue is, as i guessed , there are 4 more columns whose style was display:none and is hidden and hence while dragging the other rows cells widths are shrinking. can you please tell me how to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and thought that the dragged row was the one that was shrinking.  It's hard to say what is going on without seeing all your code.  Is it possible that you don't have the columns styled to a fixed size and they are shrinking because you are dragging the widest content out of them?  If you could set up a small duplication at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for response. please find the fiddle code here. If you loop at the other rows became small when iam dragging. The dragged one is perfect. i can email the screen shot in case if you wish to see.  http://jsfiddle.net/srikanthsvr82/mZc7V/4/

Comment: Is your test case exhibiting this behavior in jsfiddle?  I have tried it in Firefox, Chrome and Safari and do not see the shrinking you're talking about, although Chrome and Safari force a left-margin indent while dragging. (???)  

Also, your fiddle example seems to be cut from a much bigger project with a lot of superfluous code hanging around.  I think if you are able to duplicate the issue in fiddle then you should pare down the code to eliminate some of that and make it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Lastly, I don't see any styling data.  Does your project have some CSS defined somewhere?

Comment: I just noticed also that you're calling **sortable** on the reportTableBody class, but that class does not exist in the fiddle code.

Comment: yeah...the css is defined in seperate files. i will pull the css code here asap, since i want to replicate exactly whats happening i copied the entire code here

Comment: thanks for the reply, to be precise actually am facing the same issue as present in the below jquery bug .. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9185.  we have the table-layout as fixed and hence while dragging other rows widths are shrinking and we cannot change the table-layout to auto so please help me with the code on how we can solve this jquery bug.

Comment: Great work in finding that bug report ticket!  I was able to see the issue in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SCnJ/) that they provided.  Notice also that the bug has been fixed!  All you need to do is use a jQuery-ui >= version 1.10.3. I forked their fiddle and tried it with 1.10.3 and the issue goes away.  Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mcoomey/JPC4J/1/).

Comment: yeah thanks @mcoomey .I am using jquery 1.10.3 only and using table-layout the issue wud be fixed but my team is not in favour of changing the table-layout to auto and instead asked me to find some other solution. Do you know an alternative way of fixing without changing the table-layout?

Comment: @user3496151: The fix that I demonstrated in the previous [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcoomey/JPC4J/1/) was not related to the table layout of auto versus fixed.  The fiddle shows that it works for both. If you are still seeing a problem while using the newer version of jQuery-ui, then it must be another issue with your code.  Unless you are able to demonstrate the problem with displayed code then I'm afraid there's not much more I can do to help you out.

Comment: ..yeah ur correct i wish i could have shown the screen shot on how the rows width is shrinking. basically this is the css which is causing problem.                                            .fixed-table-container-inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto; }

.fixed-table-container-inner table {
  table-layout: fixed; }

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my (and hopefully other’s shrinking table rows); you need to set each cell class, or remove it from, the placeholder row. I cleared all ‘class’ and ‘colspan’ first just to be sure the original values were copied in with no overlap or residuals …

```
----- css ----
.ui-sortable-helper {
    display: table;
}
```

and on whatever selector for your sortable table

```
----- js -----
$('tbody').sortable({
  placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
  handle: '.handle',
  helper: function(e, tr) {
    var helper;
    helper = tr.clone();
    helper.css('display', '');
    return helper;
  },
  start: function(event, ui) {
    return ui.placeholder.children().each(function(index, child) {
      var source;
      source = ui.helper.children().eq(index);
      $(child).removeAttr('class').removeAttr('colspan');
      $(child).addClass(source.attr('class'));
      if (source.attr('colspan')) {
        return $(child).attr('colspan', source.attr('colspan'));
      }
    });
  }
});
```